# Delete test in rspec - change(Model, :count) failing - Why is reload needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

**TLDR: App.count needs a reload to see a created record. Why?**

I've found lots of references to testing a DELETE method that look like this:

```
expect { delete_request }.to change(App, :count).by(-1)
```

This makes sense, and works in some similar scenarios.  However, I'm seeing an issue when testing for a delete that should NOT work, such as when no user is logged in.

Here is where I started, with two approaches to testing the same thing:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe V1::AppsController, type: :controller do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:app) { create(:app, account: user.account) }

  describe 'DELETE destroy when you are not logged in' do
    let(:delete_request) { delete :destroy, id: app, format: :json }

    it 'does not delete the app (.count)' do
      expect { delete_request }.not_to change(App, :count)
    end

    it 'does not delete the app (.exists?)' do
      delete_request
      expect(App.exists?(app.id)).to eq(true)
    end
  end
end
```

This is what rspec said:

```
V1::AppsController
  DELETE destroy when you are not logged in
    does not delete the app (.count) (FAILED - 1)
    does not delete the app (.exists?)

Failures:

  1) V1::AppsController DELETE destroy when you are not logged in does not delete the app (.count)
     Failure/Error: expect { delete_request }.not_to change(App, :count)
       expected #count not to have changed, but did change from 0 to 1
     # ./spec/controllers/v1/delete_test_1.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2 examples, 1 failure
```

Note the most perplexing part: `expected #count not to have changed, but did change from 0 to 1` .  HUH?  I attempt to make an illegal delete, and my record count *grows* by one?  Also note that checking explicitly checking the subject record still exists works.

So I played around some more and found I could fix the problem with a reload prior to expect() :

```
it 'does not delete the app (.count)' do
  puts "App.count is #{App.count} (after create(:app))"
  app.reload
  puts "App.count is #{App.count} (after reload)"
  expect { delete_request }.not_to change(App, :count)
  puts "App.count is #{App.count} (after request)"
end
```

Now rspec is happy:

```
V1::AppsController
  DELETE destroy when you are not logged in
App.count is 0 (after create(:app))
App.count is 1 (after reload)
App.count is 1 (after request)
    does not delete the app (.count)
    does not delete the app (.exists?)

2 examples, 0 failures
```

From all this, I've decided to stick with the `exists?` approach.  But another (possibly bigger) concern is that all the samples of tests I found on the interwebs to test for creating records like `expect { create_request }.to change(App, :count).by(1)` might be false positives, if they are seeing the same result as I am, and assuming the record was created when in fact it was a caching artifact?

So, any idea why App.count needs a `reload` to see the current value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because when ruby invokes the `delete_request` method, it invokes the `app` method, and it creates one `App`

To test this, create the app before calling the `expect` rspec method:

```
it 'does not delete the app (.count)' do
  app #creates the app
  expect { delete_request }.not_to change(App, :count)
end
```

Take a look at `let`'s documentation:

> Use let to define a memoized helper method. The value will be cached
>   across multiple calls in the same example but not across examples.
>
> **Note that let is lazy-evaluated**: it is not evaluated until the first
>   time the method it defines is invoked. You can use let! to force the
>   method's invocation before each example.

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-11/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

Comment: Perfect, Rodrigo!  I tried mentioning `app` before expect, and using `let!`, and either approach solved the problem.  Thanks for the fix and the reference.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/dhempy/342a841b5650e842bbe7 demonstrates the issue, and the two solutions.